# Table expand & collapse not working in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below is the tabular structure for expand & collapse, i have done using table. Now i have used the below script for collapse & expand. But sometime i succeeded in expand & sometime don't.

What i did, when i got response from the api, i call this function :

```
$timeout(function (){
                    $scope.initExpandCollapse();
                },1000);


$scope.initExpandCollapse = function () {
       angular.element(document).on("click", ".table_exp", function(){
             var TBODY = angular.element(this).parents(3);
        if(TBODY.hasClass("open")){
            TBODY.children("tr.expand-table-row").hide();
            TBODY.removeClass("open");
            return false;
        }
        TBODY.addClass("open");
        TBODY.children("tr.expand-table-row").show();
    });
 }
```

[image]

If you guys, can help me out for this problem . Thanks.

Comment: Why you have used timeout?

Comment: With angular, you really should not manipulate the DOM like you do but set classes conditionally with `ng-class`.

Comment: @johannes , any suggestion how can i achieve it.?

Comment: @viktor i have used $timeout so that it loads after dom load

Comment: The controller code will only run after the DOM is loaded. Also, you can use `angular.element(document).ready()` or `$scope.init()`

Comment: @Italo, dud ya you are right, i know but  just  try as i am stuck in this problem for more than 2 hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CSS**:

```
tr.expand-table-row {
   display: none;
}

tr.expand-table-row.open {
   display: initial;
}
```

**Angular**

```
$scope.expandCollapse = function expandCollapse (item) {
    item.open = !item.open
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items track by $index"">
      <td ng-click="expandCollapse(item)">++++</td>
      <td>
          <table>
            <tr ng-class="{'open': item.open}" class="expand-table-row open">
              <td>{{item.name}}</td>
              <td ng-repeat="data in item.options">{{data.name}}</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
      </td>  
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You need nested tables so the click marker does not simply vanish with the rest, apart from that the salient point is the `ng-class="{'open': item.open}"` espression that sets the class `open` if the property `open` on item is set.

Comment: @johnannes jander, thanks for the answer. I think this is the correct way. I have created a plunkr for your code. please look over there & correct. http://plnkr.co/edit/0Bo2KUx6jhQgnjGBdcCI?p=preview

Comment: You made a copy and past error, I have corrected it and made it a nested table so the clicked line does not completely vanish. See here: http://plnkr.co/edit/CU4Q5MUoYhG7J7g4KP4B?p=preview

Comment: @ johnannes, I have made some changes according to my requirement & its working for me. Thanks for the +1 answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `window.onload` instead of `$timeout`, or add you script to the end of body tag.